# SQL Query too many rows

Tags: sql-server

I have  two tables Table a and Table B

Table A = 75 rows

Column1 , column 2

Table b = 1200 rows

Column 3, Column 4

I want all the rows in table A to be returned so that I ONLY have 75 rows returned and that's all from table A.  The resulting set should have 75 rows and 4 columns

Result:

Column 1, column 2, column 3, column 4

But no matter what join I use in SQL  I get more than 75 rows returned because table B has some records that do not match, or it has multiple records related to Table A.

How can I ONLY return 75 rows from Table a and not more than 75?

```
SELECT dbo.[00-AA].ImageTag AS [Column 1], 
       dbo.[00-AA].DateIndexed AS [Column 2],       
       dbo.[00-AW].UserId AS [Column 3], 
       dbo.[00-AW].Status AS [Column 4]
FROM dbo.[00-AA] 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[00-AW] ON dbo.[00-AA].ImageTag = dbo.[00-AW].Barcode
```

Comment: I think you are looking to group and aggregate your data. Could you share more details on column2, 3, 4 so what kind of aggregation would be suitable.

Comment: You will get more than 75 rows when there are multiple rows in Table b with a `Barcode` that matches Table A's `ImageTag1`.  What do you want to do with those multiple rows?  Choose one at random, choose the `min` or `max`, choose the aggregate in some way like `sum`??

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is that the second table has many records for every record on the first table, so you still need to tell the query which of those many records use.

This sample returns the first random record on [00-AW] with the same Barcode as the ImageTag on [00-AA].

```
with CTE as (
  select Barcode, UserId, Status,
         row_number() over (partition by Barcode order by (select null)) as NUM
  from dbo.[00-AW]
)
SELECT dbo.[00-AA].ImageTag AS [Column 1], 
       dbo.[00-AA].DateIndexed AS [Column 2],       
       CTE.UserId AS [Column 3], 
       CTE.Status AS [Column 4]
FROM dbo.[00-AA] 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE ON CTE.Barcode = dbo.[00-AA].ImageTag AND CTE.NUM = 1
```

If you want to chose a certain record on [00-AW] instead of the first random record with that Barcode, you just have to replace the `(select null)` by the fields to order that selection, so the first record is the one that it will be returned.